# Mongoose findOne on object property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema as follows

```
var user_schema = new Schema({
    reset : { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }
});
```

where reset is being given an object like this to store in the database

```
{
    id: 23,
    name: 'something'
}
```

I would like to look up a document based on the id in the reset object. This is what I have tried but I never get a result returned.

```
models.Users.findOne({ 'reset.id': id }, function (err, user) {
    // user is null 
});
```

Is a lookup like this possible with mongoose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is with using mixed schema type.

Could you not use an embedded doc of `Reset`

```
var reset_schema = new Schema({
    id        : Int,
    name      : String
});

var user_schema = new Schema({
    name      : String,
    reset     : reset_schema 
});
```

And then querying like:

```
models.Users.findOne({ 'reset.id': id }, function (err, user) {

});
```